# Python path as url, absolute local path, relative local path

Tags: python, url, path

```
import requests
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.request
import urllib
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError    

def fix_url(self,filename):
        new_filename = filename
        try:
            r = requests.get(filename, verify=False, timeout=5)
            urllib.version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36 SE 2.X MetaSr 1.0'
            new_filename = "downloaded-"+filename.split("//")[-1].split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]+".mp3"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(filename, new_filename)


        except Exception as e:
            new_filename = os.path.abspath(filename)

        return new_filename
```

The above method has input a filepath.
The filepath would be one of the following:

- valid Url
- invalid url
- local path to an existing file (relative)
- local path to an existing file (absolute)

Is the following method correct?

How can i improve this method?

Comment: Why do you import specific errors only to have your `except` statement to use a generic one?

Comment: @mapf Because with requests.get i can set the timeout (case url doesn't exists) and with urllib.request.urlretrieve i can download the file. Python version 3.x.
I want timeout with download but it's not possible as i think.

Comment: I see. So you are saying that you would like to cover all potential exceptions, so you use a generic one? I mean, this is probably nitpicking, but you could just put all the specific ones in a tuple like so `except (URLError, HTTPError) as e:`.  That way you avoid catching 'unwanted' exceptions with that statement.

Comment: @mapf and ValueError